# typeerror: app.use() requires middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean

I am learning node.js with express template engine, I am following udemy course "learn node.js by building 10 projects", while following a lecture when professor run `npm start localhost:3000` starts while mine pops up error indicating **app.use requires middleware function**
I have tried matching code and its same. Please help me to resolve the error i have been stuck here for hours tried a lot of edits but its not working for me.

**When I am trying to run 'npm start' following error pops up**

> TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions

**Here is app.js code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//Handle File Uploads
app.use(multer({
  dest: './uploads'
}));

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

//Handle Express Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialied: true,
  resave: true
}));

//Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.'),
      root = namespace.shift(),
      formParam = root;

    while (namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param: formParam,
      msg: msg,
      value: value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});



module.exports = app;
```

**Here is package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "nodeauth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "express-validator": "*",
    "express-session": "*",
    "express-messages": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "multer": "*"
  }
}
```

Here is updated app.js (after removing multar)

```
var express          = require('express'),
    path             = require('path'),
    favicon          = require('serve-favicon'),
    logger           = require('morgan'),
    cookieParser     = require('cookie-parser'),
    expressValidator = require('express-validator'),
    session          = require('express-session'),
    passport         = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy    = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    bodyParser       = require('body-parser'),
    flash            = require('connect-flash'),
    mongo            = require('mongodb'),
    mongoose         = require('mongoose'),

    db = mongoose.connection,

    routes = require('./routes/index'),
    users  = require('./routes/users'),

    app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// handle file uploads

//multer delted


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// handle express sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.'),
        root      = namespace.shift(),
        formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }

    return {
      param: formParam,
      msg  : msg,
      value: value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// flash
app.use(flash());

// express messages
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


//Express server
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

server.listen(3000, 'localhost');
server.on('listening', function() {
    console.log('Express server started on port %s at %s', server.address().port, server.address().address);
});

module.exports = app;
```

Thank You

Comment: You need to add the error in detail!

Comment: I am unable to add image it required 10 points :(

Comment: @Tushar : Sir here is link to screenshot of error:
http://postimg.org/image/hn8blsqi9/

Comment: Step one in debugging an error is finding the line where the error occurred. Which line is 206 of /lib/application.js?

Comment: that is express lib file and that code is not modified by me,

Comment: @Kevin B : Sir i have found 
 var fns = flatten(slice.call(arguments, offset));

  if (fns.length === 0) {
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
  }

but unable to figureout it.

Comment: Then go up one level in the stack trace, to /app.js:40, meaning line 40 of app.js

Comment: Can you please copy the text from the console and paste it as text in your question? having it as an image is pretty annoying.. kinda hard to copy text out of an image.

Comment: at line 38 'Uninitialized' typo error is corrected, I have already posted screenshot of error, if you have teamviewer i can share my details

Comment: You still haven't told us what is line 40 of app.js.

Comment: I have resolved the error by removing multer  from code,

Comment: It is running after removing multar I am posting new code

Comment: If you've solved teh problem, make it an answer. If not, clarify your question to make the problem more clear. As it is now, you've got way too much code in your question.

Comment: Problem still not resolved as i am still trying to add multar but it is not working then, so as soon as i sort out how to add multar i will either delete or mark as ans whatever good for the community.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Delete this line,

```
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads' }));
```

and use instead

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
```

Comment: I am really sorry but i lost access to my this new google account earlier, and somehow got access now, thanks for helping me :)

Comment: My answer is younger and wider than this, why didnt check it instead?

Comment: Node should have displayed a more descriptive error message

Answer (score 27):

Change:

```
//Handle File Uploads
app.use(multer({
  dest: './uploads'
}));
```

For something like:

```
app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('singleInputFileName'));
```

or

```
app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).array('multiInputFileName'));
```

And be aware to have something like:

```
<form action="/postPhotos" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="singleInputFileName">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload photo">
</form>
```

for the first case, or:

```
<form action="/postPhotos" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="multiInputFileName" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload photo">
</form>
```

For the second one, in your html.

Comment: I have removed the multer but now let me add again,

Answer (score 11):

This worked with me:

```
app.use(multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')
}).any());
```

Answer (score 9):

I was also doing that course & ran into the same  problem. I resolved the error by following the Multer usage instructions from their github: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

Here is the code from their README:

```
    var multer  = require('multer')
    var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

& here is the code I used to overcome the error while doing that tutorial:

```
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I am really sorry but i lost access to my this new google account earlier, and somehow got access now, thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 3):

you can simply use :

```
app.set(multer({dest: "./uploads"}));
```

it works for me too.