# It doesn't validate when If I write things to form inputs are even correct. It gives all errors everytime

Tags: node.js, validation, pug

I m learning from fast record on youtube. calls "Learn NodeJS building 10 projects". he is doing that at 15. video. Well this is my first post here. dont yell me cuz its my first message here. and please use easy english :) salute from turkey.

```
///THIS IS THE APP.JS
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//handle file uploads multer
//app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads'}));
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });


// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// handle express-session
app.use(session({
    secret:'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave:true
}));
// passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// express-validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// connect-flash
app.use(flash());

// express-messages
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
------------------------------
 THIS IS THE USERS.JS
------------------------------

    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET users listing. */

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.send('respond with a resource');
    });

    router.get('/yenihesap', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('yenihesap',{
        'title': 'Yeni Hesap Aç'      
      });
    });

    router.get('/giris', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('giris',{
        'title': 'Giriş Yap'      
      });
    });

    router.get('/sifremiunuttum', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('sifremiunuttum',{
        'title': 'Şifremi Unuttum'    
      });
    });

    router.post('/yenihesap', function(req, res, next){

        // get form values
        var name = req.body.name;
        var lastname = req.body.lastname;
        var email = req.body.email;
        var password = req.body.password;
        var password2 = req.body.password2;

        // form validation
        req.checkBody('name', 'Lütfen isminizi giriniz').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('lastname', 'Lütfen soyadınızı giriniz').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Lütfen email adresinizi giriniz').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('email', 'Bu bir email adresi değil!').isEmail();
        req.checkBody('password', 'Lütfen şifrenizi giriniz').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('password2', 'Şifreniz eşleşmiyor!').equals(req.body.password);

        // check for errors
        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
            res.render('yenihesap',{
                errors: errors,
                name: name,
                lastname: lastname,
                email: email,
                password: password,
                password2: password2
            });
        }else{
            var newUser = new User({
                name: name,
                lastname: lastname,
                email: email,
                password: password
            });

            // create user
            //User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            //  if(err) throw err;
            //  console.log(user);
            //});

            //succes message
            req.flash('success', 'Başarıyla kayıt oldunuz');
            res.location('/');
            res.redirect('/');  
        }
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

[this is the jade file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUkTq.png)

[when even i full up to input forms correctly, all errors that i have. i dont understand why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwaKf.png)

Comment: You need `body-parser` package

Comment: I added to my question the app.js file now. I have it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Its about the multer. first of all it wasnt work with that code at the beggining

```
  //handle file uploads multer
  app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads'}));
```

the multer was giving me error and changed it to that

```
  //handle file uploads multer
  var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });
```

and this time multer had me this question problem that body parser wasnt work. so I changed to that. and it fixed my problem. I found it another question on stackover: [typeerror: app.use() requires middleware function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656178/typeerror-app-use-requires-middleware-function)

```
 //handle file uploads multer
 app.use(multer({dest:'./uploads/'}).single('singleInputFileName'));
```

I m happy to joined this site. Its obviously perfect that people help each other. see you on next problems :)