# type error: app.use() requires middleware

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I can not figure out why I get this error.

When I try to run `node filename.js`, I got a type error on the console:

> app.use() requires middleware functions

I expect the result is:

> Working on port 3000

Below is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var DIR = './uploads/';
var upload = multer({dest: DIR});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://valor-software.github.io');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});

app.use(multer({
  dest: DIR,
  rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename + Date.now();
  },
  onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
  },
  onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
  }
}));

app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.end('file catcher example');
});

app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.end(err.toString());
    }
    res.end('File is uploaded');
  });
});

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log('Working on port ' + PORT);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33369258/4486609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [document of multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#usage) on npm. You can not pass `multer` object as an argument directly. You should pass them by calling member functions, such as `single()`, `field()`, `array()`.

For example:

```
upload = multer({
  dest: DIR,
  rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
    return filename + Date.now();
  },
  onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
    console.log(file.originalname + ' is starting ...');
  },
  onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
    console.log(file.fieldname + ' uploaded to  ' + file.path);
  }
})

app.use(upload.single(...));
app.use(upload.array(...));
app.use(upload.fields(...));
app.use(upload.any());
```