# middleware function error in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I unable to run node main file in terminal
and I am using handlebar as template engine

getting this weird error
 I did npm install all dependencies which is required. but still getting this error.

```
/home/mohsin/Desktop/mohsin/react/react-web-app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:210
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
```

this is error screenshot please have look https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUBhU.png

My app.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-sessions');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Port env
const port = 3000;

// Route files
 const index = require('./routes/index');
const user = require('./routes/user');

  // Init App
  const app = express();

  // View Engine
    app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
   app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

   // Static Folder
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

   // Body parser middleware
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

     // Express Session
      app.use(session({
secret: 'secret',
saveUninitialized: true,
resave: true
 }));



 // Start server
 app.use('/', index);
 app.use('/user', user);

  // Start Server
 app.listen(port, () => {
 console.log('Server started on port '+port);
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typeerror: app.use() requires middleware function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31656178/typeerror-app-use-requires-middleware-function)

Comment: no I refer that this is not duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no package named `'express-sessions'`
instead use `express-session` 
so its not returning any method. which app.use can call as method. 
Here is [package](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Comment: actually I looked at this and there is one :) - but yeah, probably a typo